# Rake file is seeing old version of database on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, rake

I'm using a rakefile to seed my database. I was seeing weird behavior (see [Additional user attributes results in UnknownAttributeError and NoMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636966/additional-user-attributes-results-in-unknownattributeerror-and-nomethoderror)) and have concluded that it is operating on an old version of my database (at the very least, an old version of my Users table, perhaps more).

- Running the rakefile on localhost works fine
- On Heroku, printing User.column_names within the rakefile shows the old version of the table
- On Heroku, printing User.column_names from within the main app shows the new version of the table
- Within Heroku rails console, User.column_names shows the new version of the table

Any ideas how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to make sure you do on heroku is restart your dynos correctly. A client of mine once tried something like this:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate db:seed_data
```

Heroku's documentation at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake mentions that you should restart your app in between migrations:

> After running a migration you’ll want to restart your app with heroku
>   restart to reload the schema and pickup any schema changes.

So the answer might be to not batch it in the same process; i.e. try something like

```
heroku run rake db:migrate; heroku run rake db:seed_data
```

Comment: You nailed it, I was running: `heroku pg:reset DATABASE -a <app-name>; heroku run rake db:migrate demo:add_data -a <app-name>`